# shell script odd regex

Tags: regex, bash, shell, centos6

i have some regex that is behaving oddly in my shell script i have variables, and i have tried every what way to get them to behave, and they dont seem to do any regex, and i know my regex quite well thanks to [regex101](http://regex101.com), here is what a sample looks like

```
fname="direcheck"
FIND="*"
if [[ $fname =~ $FIND ]]; then
echo "no quotes"
fi

if [[ "$fname" =~ "$FIND" ]]; then
echo "with quotes"
fi
```

right now it will display nothing
if i change find to

```
FIND="[9]*"
```

then it prints no quotes
if i say

```
FIND="[a-z]*"
```

then it prints no quotes

if i say

```
FIND="dircheck"
```

then nothing prints

if i say

```
FIND="*ck"
```

then nothing prints

I don't get how this regex is working

**how do i use these variables, and what is the proper syntax**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out, and why it was working so oddly

[a-z]* and [9]* and [anythinghere]* they all match because it matches zero or more times. so "direcheck" has [9] zero or more times.

so

```
 if [[ "$fname" =~ $FIND ]]; then
```

or

```
 if [[ $fname =~ $FIND ]]; then
```

are both correct, and

```
if [[ "$fname" =~ "$FIND" ]]; then
```

matches only when the string matches exactly because `$FIND` is matched as a literal string not regex

Answer (score 1):

- `*` and `*ck` are invalid regular expressions. It would work (with no quotes) if you were comparing with `==`, not `=~`. If you want to use the same functionality that you get in `==` for them, the equivalent regexps are `.*` and `.*ck`.
- `[9]*` is any number (including zero) of characters that are `9`. There is zero characters `9` in your `direcheck`, so it matches. (Edited from brainfart, thanks chepner)
- `dircheck` is not found in `direcheck`, so not printing anything is hardly surprising.
- `[a-z]*` is any number of characters that are between `a` and `z` (i.e. any number of lowercase letters). This will match, assuming it's not quoted.

Comment: @ritesht93: Yup, 1st point. Globs are `==`, regexps are `=~`.

Comment: also dont mix up `glob` and `=~` regex

Comment: Strictly speaking, `*` is a *valid* regular expression; it matches a string containing an asterisk. Without a token to modify, an asterisk loses its special meaning as a quantifier, and becomes merely an asterisk. For example, `printf 'one*\ntwo\n' | grep '*'`.

Comment: @ghoti: Dialects differ. In bash dialect, that is not true: `[[ '*' =~ * ]] && echo yep || echo nope` says "nope". In Ruby's Oniguruma dialect, Perl's PCRE dialect and JavaScript's dialect, `/*/` is a syntax error. True, Ruby, Perl and JS are irrelevant here; but `grep` is equally so.

Comment: so you are telling me that if `[[ $fname =~ $FIND ]];` then is the proper syntax? if it is, then why in the world does both `[9]*` match and `[a-z]*` match?!? and i tested it with `$FIND="direcheck"`, and it matched quotes and not quotes

Comment: Regular expressions aren't anchored to the beginning or end of the string they match. `[9]*` and `[a-z]*` both successfully match the empty string, which is a substring of *any* argument.